# Hide item when download starts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that when clicked, downloads a file, but the file gets built when the user clicks a link. It searches the database loads the data and writes it into an excel file.

This can take up to 30 seconds, so I do this to hide the download link and show a loading animation.

Here is my Link:

```
<a class="download-link" href="?page=pev&amp;action=downloadreport&amp;id=1234">
    <img src="/media/images/download.png" height="30" width="30" />
</a>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("click", ".download-link", function(){
    showMetro();
    $('.page').hide();
});

function showMetro(){
    $(".metro-loader").css("display", "inline-block");
}
```

Once the download starts, how can I reverse the effect, where I hide the loading animation and show the page again?

Comment: `the file gets built when the user clicks a link`. So there's some "server side action" somewhere ? no ? Couldn't you, then, use ajax and a callback function ?

Comment: Yes, you would hide the loading animation and `show()` the page again. If you are asking how to know when the download finishes, that depends on how you implemented it.

Comment: The file doesn't get saved on the server, it just gets written to the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using ajax to tell the server to generate the file so add this to your success callback.

```
$(".metro-loader").hide();
$('.page').show();
```